# How to fetch COMPLETE data from Cumulocity using cep

Tags: cumulocity

I am currently getting data using event processing tab at administration tab using cep queries,but only the data after i save the query is fetched .How can we query based on complete set of data ?

```
 @Name("CarLoadWeekly")
 @Resilient
 insert into createEvent
 select "vechiclecount" as type ,e.event.time as time   from EventCreated as e
 where  (e.text ='active')
```

Answer (score 0):

The event processing is a pure realtime engine. The scripts that you deploy there will be injected into the realtime stream of data and do not apply for historical data.

If you need to access historical data within your realtime script there are certain functions where you can query historical data. You can take a look at the [analytics guide](https://cumulocity.com/guides/event-language/functions/) for that.